# Is the boss spawn completely random?

Tags: killing-floor-2

In Killing Floor 2, the boss of a game can be either [Hans Volter](https://wiki.tripwireinteractive.com/index.php?title=Dr._Hans_Volter) *or* the [Patriarch](https://wiki.tripwireinteractive.com/index.php?title=Patriarch_(Killing_Floor_2)). The Patriarch is **objectively** more difficult than Hans Volter, so I was wondering if anything affects which one will spawn.

That is, is there a 50/50 chance for either of them to spawn, or does the difficulty level make the Patriarch more likely to spawn, for example? I have noticed that I occasionally fight the same boss two games in a row, so it's not a simple alternation.

Comment: I just got the game and disagree that Patriarch is harder :P I've killed him a few times and haven't been able to finish off Hans.

Comment: @n_palum Hans is easier because you can prevent his heal by unloading a clip into him, while Patriarch goes invisible and runs to god knows where

Comment: I get that, we just burn down patriarch really fast as a group because he's a big target.

Comment: @n_palum don't take this the wrong way, but do you play on normal difficulty? Hans is unquestionably easier.

Comment: @LostWookie I play on at least Hard. Not sure why we struggle with him more ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When Tripwire announced the patriarch and put him in Killing Floor 2, they announced that each map would have a 50/50 chance for either the patriarch or Volter. Tripwire wanted the final boss to be a toss up each round, so players do not know and strategize for a specific boss. This uncertainty adds a bit of difficulty to Killing Floor 2, which already is no walk in the park.

For reference, pcgamer published an article for the [patriarch](http://www.pcgamer.com/killing-floor-2-patriarch-boss-reveal/) announcement.

Comment: Ah, that's both good and bad, I guess. I found where it mentions the randomness of the spawn in the article myself, but you should edit that bit into the answer as a quote to make it easier to see.